# Financial formulation in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, oracle-sqldeveloper, finance, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I need help with creating a trial balance report for a specific tenure, from beginning of fiscal year to a selected period. I need this in Crystal Reports.

I am unable to formulate how can I get debit and credit amounts totalling from beginning of the fiscal year till the end of selected period (not YTD).

For example, I want to get a trial balance report till period 6 (June), I am able to get the balance at the end of period 6, but unable to formulate total credits and total debits for selected number of periods/months. Instead, it is either debit/credit amounts for June or it's for total debit/credits till date.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What accounting system/software are you using?  Some accounting systems have database functions or procedures specifically for calculating the balance of a GL account as of a specific date and time.

Comment: I am using DelmiaWorks ERP (former IQMS). It does have As Of and YTD reports but none of these include starting Beginning, Total Debits/Credits and ending Balance for a certain range of dates.

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula that returns, for each record, it's dollar amount if it's within the target date range, otherwise, zero.

Sum that formula to get the total for that time period.

Comment: Can you please share an example, if possible? 
I am a noob to SQL formulation and hence, haven't actually got a hold of what you advised.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a user of the DelmiaWorks/IQMS ERP solution as well.  IQMS uses a stored procedure to populate a database table named "C_TRIAL_BALANCE_AS_OF".  When you publish a report into IQMS, there is a field named "Execute Before Print" on the Edit Report Definition window that opens when edit a report.  To run this stored procedure in conjunction with another report, you will want to choose "POP_C_TRIAL_BALANCE_AS_OF" in the drop-down box control for this field.  This will ensure the procedure is run prior to the report so you have the account balances you need as of a specified date.  When the report is executed, IQMS will present the user with a Date Picker for the As Of Date.  Almost all of the data you need to do a Trial Balance report can be found on this calculated table.  The only joins needed should be "V_GLYEAR_PERIODS", "V_GLACCT", and "EPLANT".

There is a built-in report that may do what you want already though.  If you begin the Trial Balance module and then click "Reports" > "Print" to bring up the list of all reports, then look for one named "Trial Balance As Of".  Even if this report is lacking some information you need, it will likely be much easier to edit this existing report than it would be to create one from scratch.

If you don't have this built-in report, you may be able to get a copy of the RPT file from their support department.  As long as you have the Trial Balance module, you should have this report.  Its a standard report that is included in every version of IQMS I've worked with.  However, my experience is limited to the 15.3 and 2020 versions.